# What's wrong with my code; constructors and loops?

Tags: java

This is my driver class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class PizzaMatch {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String answer = "";
        String yes = "Y";
        String no = "N";
        String topping = "";
        int size = 0;
        double cost = 0;
        int iteration = 0;
        int inFileSize = 0;
        double inFileCost = 0;
        String inFileTopping = "";

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inFileReader = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Frosty Snow/Downloads/pizza.txt"));

        System.out.println("Would you like to enter a Pizza? (Y or N)");
        answer = reader.next();

        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(no)) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Input a Pizza topping, size, and cost:");
        topping = reader.next();
        size = reader.nextInt();
        cost = reader.nextDouble();

        Pizza Order = new Pizza (size, topping, cost);

        while(inFileReader.hasNextLine())
        {
            iteration ++;
            inFileSize = inFileReader.nextInt();
            inFileTopping = inFileReader.next();
            inFileCost = inFileReader.nextDouble();

            Pizza inFileOrder = new Pizza(inFileSize, inFileTopping, inFileCost);

            if(Order.equals(inFileOrder))
            {
                System.out.println("That pizza is # " + iteration + " in the file.");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is my resource class

```
public class Pizza {

   private int size;
   private String topping;
   private double cost;


   public Pizza()
   {
      size = 10;
      topping = "cheese";
      cost = 9.00;
   }

   public Pizza(int s, String t, double c)
   {
      size = s;
      topping = t;
      cost = c;   }

   public int getSize() {
      return size;
   }

   public void setSize(int s) {
      s = size;
   }

   public String getTopping(){
      return topping;
   }

   public void setTopping(String t){
      topping = t;
   }

   public void setCost(double c) {
      cost = c;
   }   

   public double getCost(double c){
      return cost;
   }
   public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
      if(!(obj instanceof Pizza))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      Pizza temp = (Pizza) obj;

      if (this.size == temp.size && this.topping.equals(temp.topping) && this.cost == temp.cost)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format("%d inch %s pizza will cost $%,.2f\n", size, topping, cost);

   }
}
```

These are my errors

```
Would you like to enter a Pizza? (Y or N)
sloppyJoe 15 15.30
Input a Pizza topping, size, and cost:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at PizzaMatch.main(PizzaMatch.java:34)

Would you like to enter a Pizza? (Y or N)
Y
Input a Pizza topping, size, and cost:
sloppyJoe 15 15.30
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at PizzaMatch.main(PizzaMatch.java:42)
```

I think the issue has to do with the while statement, reading the next line. Is there something else I could put in its place? Please inform me if there's anything else that could messing me up.

pizza.txt

```
cheese 12 12.50
sausage 15 21.89
peppers 10 15.05
pineapple 40 33.00
pepperoni 11 10.22
olive 9 8.99
xcheese 13 9.66
supreme 13 15.22
mushroom 17 16.34
bbqchicken 14 20.13
pepperoni 10 11.70
sausage 12 11.89
peppers 12 15.05
pineapple 14 13.50
squirrel 12 12.24
pickle 12 7.99
hawaiian 10 13.00
pepperoni 11 10.22
meat 13 9.66
sloppyJoe 15 15.30
dessert 14 17.60
bigBubba 16 25.00
steakLovers 23 30.77
bison 10 11.70
secretMeat 12 11.99
peppers 12 14.00
pineNeedle 13 13.50
sweetTart 12 12.24
tofu 7 8.99
```

Comment: It looks like you are entering info before it asks you. Is this really what you want? You typed "sloppyJoe 15 15.30" before you were asked to.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated it.

Comment: `at PizzaMatch.main(PizzaMatch.java:42)` Which line is #42 in `PizzaMatch`?

Comment: inFileSize = inFileReader.nextInt();

Comment: If you want to ignore the rest of a line you need to call reader.nextLine(); Otherwise next() will continue to read the current line.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't "next()" only read string values though?

Comment: It would seem that the first item in that file is not an int.

Comment: Care to give us the pizza.txt file? I would like to see how its format

Comment: better, if you post the exact content of "pizza.txt" you have used.

Comment: While reading from the file you are getting items in this order "Size Topping Cost" but your file is in this order "Topping Size Cost". `inFileSize = inFileReader.nextInt();` tries to get an int but instead gets a String, hence `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: So I should change the order?

Comment: Either change the order of the items in the file or the order in which you read them. They must be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The ordering must be changed

```
        inFileSize = inFileReader.nextInt();
        inFileTopping = inFileReader.next();
        inFileCost = inFileReader.nextDouble();
```

to

```
        inFileTopping = inFileReader.next();
        inFileSize = inFileReader.nextInt();
        inFileCost = inFileReader.nextDouble();
```

This is because your file contains the names of the toppings first. So you have to first read the `inFileTopping` first.

The output after changing will be

```
Would you like to enter a Pizza? (Y or N)
Y       
Input a Pizza topping, size, and cost:
cheese 12 12.50
That pizza is # 1 in the file.
```

For more details

the first line of the file

```
cheese 12 12.50
```

Here the topping is at first. You are trying to read it as a size, which is giving you the error

Comment: @Newbie Do consider accepting this answer as correct. Else others will think that your question is still un-answered. See this link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work